# Foundry convert uploaded csv to dataframe

Tags: pyspark, palantir-foundry

how can I convert an uploaded CSV to dataframe in foundry using a code workbook? should I use the @transform decorator with spark.read.... (not sure of the exact syntax)?

Thx!!

Comment: Do you really need to use code workbook, or are you wanting to use it because you don't know how to use code repositories? CSV parsing is better to be done as a normal transform, since the file opening and parsing process can slow down code workbooks.

Answer (score 0):

CSV is a "special format" where Foundry can infer the schema of the CSV and automatically convert it to a dataset.  In this example, I uploaded a CSV with [hail data from NOAA](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/stormevents/):

[image]

If you hit Edit Schema on the main page, you can use a front end tool to set certain configurations about the CSV (delimiter, column name row, column type etc).

[image]

Once it's a dataset, you can import the dataset in Code Workbooks and it should work out of the box.

If you wanted to parse the raw file, I would recommend you use Code Authoring, not Code Workbooks, as it's better suited for production level code, has less overhead and is more efficient for this type of workflow (parsing raw files).  If you really wanted to use code workbooks, change the type of your input using the input helper bar, or in the inputs tab.

**Once you finish iterating please move this to a Code Authoring repository and repartition your data. File reads at code workbook can substantially slow down your whole code workbook pipeline**. Code Authoring offers preview of raw files now, so it's just as fast to develop as using Code Workbooks.

[image]

Note: Only imported datasets and persisted datasets can be read in as Python transform inputs. Transforms that are not saved as a dataset cannot be read in as Python transform inputs. Datasets with no schema should be read in as a transform input automatically.

Comment: This is a great answer, I would recomend against doing parsing in code workbooks though. Once you finish iterating please move this to a code repository and repartition your data. File reads at code workbook can substantially slow down your whole code workbook pipeline

Comment: Added at comment as well in the answer.